# Disable Apache basic auth in virtual subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http-basic-authentication

I have a webserver that is completely locked down with Basic Auth

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    # [...] rest of basic auth stuff
    require valid-user
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    Satisfy any
</Location>
```

One subdirectory is accessible without auth:

```
<Location /public>
  allow from all
  Satisfy any
</Location>
```

This is working fine. Now I want to allow access without login to some scripts that are accessed with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^phonebook/show/(.+)$ /quicksearchShow.php?uid=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^phonebook/(.+)$ /quicksearch.php?s=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^phonebook$ /quicksearch.php [NC]
```

Some ways I tried:

```
<Location ~ "/phonebook*">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</Location>

<Location /phonebook>
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</Location>

<LocationMatch "^phonebook.*">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</LocationMatch>
```

None of these options work. I assume because `/phonebook` is not an actual directory on the server. So I tried some variants of the `<Files>` directives:

```
<FilesMatch "/quicksearch.*">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "^quicksearch.*">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</FilesMatch>

<Files "quicksearch.php">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any
</Files>
```

But no luck either.

So, how do I set options for a specific "virtual" directory that is mapped via mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I kinda gave up on this approach. I created a subdirectory "phonebook", moved the files in there and added this to the apache config:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(css|js|images|icons|phonebook)/">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
    Satisfy Any
</LocationMatch>
```

This works, but I was unable to get it working without the directory existing on the filesystem.